# difference from date from sql and current date using LocalDate returns 0 when setting text in a jTextField

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8

I'm trying to subtract date from sql database to current date. I tried the output in console and it works fine. The years between works properly. But when i tried to show the output in a text field it always return 0. Here is my code.

```
    public void checkDate() {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date1 = ((JTextField) 
    jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.parse(date1, dtf);
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
    int rt = Period.between(birthdate, ld).normalized().getYears();
    System.out.println(rt);
    age.setText("" + rt);
    }
```

I create a event mouseClicked to jTextField age. It always return 0. Please help

Comment: did you already check the java api ? I found this   LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
  String text = date.format(formatter);
  LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. Maybe you should debug it, because it looks correct to me. I don't understand your title, where is the "SQL" part? Is that the jDateChooser component?

Comment: please show your mouseClicked event,